# Implementing admin login ASP .Net Web application

Tags: asp.net, .net, forms, authentication

I am creating a company website that has some public and restricted pages. I want to create a couple for users that can access the restricted pages. I read about Forms Authentication but this seems to complex for the basic requirements that I have.

All I need is the login functionality. I can just manually add the users to the database. I also don't want to give the users the ability to register on the site. Is Forms Authentication worth using for this or is there a more basic approach available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form authentication is too complex? Why do you think so?

It is the most basic built-in type of authentications.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms name="SavingsPlan" loginUrl="/Login.aspx">
      <credentials passwordFormat="SHA1">
         <user name="Kim"
               password="07B7F3EE06F278DB966BE960E7CBBD103DF30CA6"/>
         <user name="John"
               password="BA56E5E0366D003E98EA1C7F04ABF8FCB3753889"/>
      </credentials>
   </forms>
</authentication>
```

---

You dont have to use the Hashing and all that, all you need to do is to put in your `web.config`:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
```

that's it, now you need a function to log in:

```
private bool IsValid(string username, string password)
{
    bool isValid = false;
    //put some logic here

    return isValid;
}
```

**Sign in:**

```
if (IsValid("someUser", "SomePassword"))
{
   FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Username, false);
}
```

**Sign Out:**

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

That's it! too complex? Why? whyyy?? `:P`

Comment: I feel so dumb. I have seen tutorials on forms authentication that uses all the built in templates and it has too many features than what  I needed that's why I said it's complex. This is perfect!!!